# When to persist user registration data to Cloud Firestore

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

In my iOS app I would like to have the following steps for account creation:

1. Email and Password account creation
2. Persist other user data like name etc.
3. User can then access app features

For initially determining if a user is authenticated and what screen they be taken to, I use a listener as recommend by Firebase.

```
    func initialAuthHandleObserver(completionHandler: @escaping (AuthStatus) -> Void) {
        Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, _) in
            if auth.currentUser == nil {
                completionHandler(.signedOut)
            } else {
                completionHandler(.signedIn)
            }
        }
    }
```

When creating an account with the Firebase auth method for email and password, the user is signed in after they successfully sign up.

However, I still need the user to provide further information like their name.

Currently this observer will get triggered after step 1 and will transition to show the app features, and would not ensure that the user has go to step 2 first before they can reach step 3.

How can I ensure that the user always goes to step 2 after completing step 1 before they can access the app features, including if the user was to exit the app after step 1?

Answer (score 1):

My typical approach would be to attach a listener to the user document early on, and then redirect based on the correct state based on what you get back.

1. If you get no document, you'll probably want to redirect to the sign-up page.
2. If you get a document, but it doesn't contain the additional information, you'll want to redirect to the "enter additional information" page.
3. If you get a document with the full user profile, redirect to the main view of your app.

Comment: Thanks Frank - from your answer I am now thinking that in the AddStateDidChangeListener completion, when I get back when the user is signed in - I could add a listener to check on the user document and proceed from there, either to step 2 or step 3. Does that seem like a good approach?

Comment: Also I never know which object to check in the AddStateDidChangeListener to verify auth status. Should I use the user object or the auth object and check auth.currentUser ??

Comment: Instead of a listener should I just do a get call to check if a user has been created in Firestore? I could then just check if the document exists

Comment: Adding a Firestore listener or doing a `get` in the `addStateDidChangeListener` sounds fine to me. In there you can either check the `user` that is passed in, or get the user from `Auth.auth().currentUser`; the result will be the same either way.